# changing a page with delay and eventListener set to click works regardles of the click

Tags: javascript, settimeout, event-listener

im trying to change an html page with a delay of 3 sec when the user clicks on a specific div in the screen.

```
document.getElementById("specificDiv").addEventListener("click", setTimeout(document.getElementById("linkToAnotherPage").click(), 3000) )
```

however the eventListener doesnt work. when the page loads up it automatically clicks on the "linkToAnotherPage" after 3 sec have past since loading the page.

would love if someone could help me understand whats wrong here.

Comment: Your setTimeout should be `setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("linkToAnotherPage").click(), 3000)`

Comment: I copied your suggestion and the problem still remains  :/
the situation is still: loading the page and after 3 sec it redirects to the next without any click given by the user

Comment: You would have to provide a more complete example. What is most likely happening is that there is a click that is happening on the page and it is 'bubbling' up to the element you are looking for. Without a more complete example though it is hard to say exactly.

Comment: you are right, my problem has been solved, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` takes a function. If you don't pass a function, it will run the code immediately. If you pass a function though, the function will be invoked after the specified time. To demonstrate:

```js
setTimeout(console.log('Hello World 2'), 5000)
setTimeout(() => console.log('Hello World 1'), 5000)
```

So your code should be updated to: `document.getElementById("specificDiv").addEventListener("click", setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("linkToAnotherPage").click(), 3000));` if you want it to wait the 3s specified before executing the click.